# Is there a generalization of Voronoi Diagrams to curves in the plane?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, theory

I've studied Voronoi Diagrams and Fortune's Algorithm before. What I'm curious about is if there's a generalization of Voronoi diagrams where instead of the input being a set of points, it is instead a set of non-intersecting curves in the plane, where we want to partition the plane into regions based off the Euclidean distance to the nearest curve.

Is this problem well defined and is there any known (hopefully efficient) algorithm to compute this generalization?

I've tried searching for an answer to this, but most resources seem to focus on curved metric spaces or curved regions rather than the input set itself being composed of non-points.

**Edit:**
If this isn't well defined for non-intersecting curves, will it work for line segments?

Comment: If two of your "non-intersecting curves" have overlapping convex hulls, where should the partition be made?

Comment: I think you would end up with non-convex regions in this case, but I don't believe that automatically poses an issue unless I'm missing something. I definitely agree that the regions formed by this process won't be as "nice" as in traditional Voronoi diagrams.

Comment: You can definitely produce a region for each curve such that all points in the region are closer to a point of that curve than to a point of any other curve. That's trivial to prove by construction, just "inflate" all the curves in all directions at the same speed without overlapping (stop locally when two inflated curves meet), and stop whenever the plane is filled. I don't think any general algorithm is going to be very efficient.

Comment: If you're working with line segments, I think there is a relatively simple way to make enclosing regions for them, but they won't be the Voronoi kind: all points in one region won't be closer to its enclosed line segment than to all other line segments. If you want that property, the regions must be able to have curved sides, so I don't think it's much easier than for arbitrary curves. So what exactly is your use case?

Comment: Another approach is to replace the curves with closely spaced points, and then run a traditional Voronoi algorithm.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20696/voronoi-diagrams-for-generators-other-than-points

Comment: @user3386109: provided you merge the domains of the points from the same curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Voronoi diagram is defined for arbitrary point sets and other distances than Euclidean. A quick web search gives you as many examples as you want. Intersecting curves are also possible.

[image]

[image]

The construction of the diagram for a set of line segments is well documented. The cells are bounded by line segments and parabolic arcs. If I am right, Fortune's algorithm generalizes to this case.

For general curves, the problem gets harder. In all cases, you need to derive the equation of bisector lines, and intersect them correctly to delimit the proper arcs at triple points.

A digitized version (on a raster grid) is easier and will work with any kind of shape. It is similar to the computation of a distance map, and can be performed in time linear in the number of pixels.